# Menu to pick up images from gallery or camera IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios

I've been searching for the IOS menu name to pick up images from user gallery or activate camera. My intention is to  show this menu once the user touches an UIImageView to select an image for his app profile.

Sorry to ask but I wasn't successful searching information.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UIActionSheet` class is used for this purpose. Here's link to Action Sheets [in Apple's HIG](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIActionSheet.html) and [API reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 1):

and a nice tutorial on this subject that I found useful:

http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/iphone/examples/PhotoLibrary.html